# how to list child teams by team id using pygithub

Tags: python, pygithub

how to get child teams by parent team id using pygithub

I can't find any API Objects corresponding the following request

```
GET /teams/:team_id/teams
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not supported yet, see https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub/issues/1054#issuecomment-468543429

> Nested Teams is still in beta, we don't current use the custom media type of hellcat-preview anywhere, so our API responses won't include them.

And from github docs https://developer.github.com/v3/teams/#list-child-teams :

> At this time, the hellcat-preview media type is required to use this endpoint.
>
> GET /teams/:team_id/teams

Comment: could you provide more details or example that using endpoint"GET /teams/:team_id/teams"

Comment: @Jeff it's not supported by PyGithub for now, but we can hack it: ``status, headers, output = g._Github__requester.requestJson('GET', '/teams/{}/teams'.format(team_id), headers={'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.hellcat-preview+json'})``

Comment: That’s helpful, Thank you support @duyue